# how to convert a base64 string in to normal image and show it in a web page in react js

Tags: reactjs

I'm using fetch to retrieve data from an API, it returns an image in base 64 string format. How can i convert it in to a normal image and show it in a web page using react?

Comment: Will you be using a simple HTML5 `<img>` tag? If so, use the standard `<img src="data:image/png[jpg];base64, [yourString]">`

Comment: @Tico, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Try to use 
`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{base64imagestring}" />`

Comment: can i send a variable(which contains base64 string) instead of base64 string?

Comment: Yes the base64imagestring  was representing a variable name in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

```
<img src={"data:image/png;base64," +  Data.Photo} />
```

this was the solution that worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

I think following information might help you.

So, [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) has encoded binary information into textual data and to decode it back you can use - [atob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob)

To show it in a web-page using react - you may consider to use "img" tag itself, as suggested by @tico in comment using data-uri.

In general [data uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs), let you put your image( and other data) in the form of url.

So, simple steps would be -
1. Fetch the base64 encoded image.
2. Make a data-uri.
3. Load the source into the image tag, using state preferably.
4. And you are done!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use this below, make sure there is no comma in between them

<img src={"data:image/png;base64" +  base64encodedimg } />